# How to prove and find, without differentiation, the limit of (3x^2-5x-2)/(5x^2-20) as x goes to 2.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find the limit of:

$$ \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{3x^2 -5x-2}{5x^2-20}$$

**without using differentiation.** I computed the graph of the function and I know that the limit should be 0,35. I assume I should use an Epsilon-Delta proof but I struggle when I want to find a suitable delta for epsilon.

If you can access [this](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/Understanding-Analysis-2nd-edition-chapter-4.2-problem-8E-solution-9781493927111) - I was trying to write a similar solution.

Also, I wanted to ask if it is possible to apply any convergence test for series and sequences to prove that a limit of a function is convergent (of a function) or if those tests (Ratio test, Integral Test, Cauchy Test, etc etc.) are reserved for infinite series or sequences only. (Here the limit goes to a specific number, so.. I don't know if it would be even relevent to mention those tests.)

If I defferentiate the answer becomes appartent but how can I go on about it without doing so? Would it be also possible to replace X with a sequence which converges to 2 and then go on from that?

Comment: If you get $\frac {0}{0}$ when you plug $x = 2,$ that would suggest that $(x-2)$ is a common factor in the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 6):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\lim_\limits{x\to2}{3x^2-5x-2\over{5x^2-20}}&=
\lim_\limits{x\to2}{3(x-2)(x+\large{1\over3})\over5(x^2-4)}\\
&=\lim_\limits{x\to2}{\bcancel3\cancel{(x-2)}(\large{3x+1\over\bcancel{3}})\over5\cancel{(x-2)}(x+2)}\\&=\lim_\limits{x\to2}{3x+1\over5(x+2)}
\\&={{7}\over{20}}=0.35\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Just divide out the factor $x-2$ from numerator and denominator.  You can do that because $x$ is guaranteed not to be $2$ when you take the limit.  Then you can just plug in because you have eliminated the indeterminate form analytically.